# Using HAVING OR WHERE?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a list of "items" which all have a "title" and contain a group of "tags":

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT i.id, i.title  
                FROM items AS i
                LEFT JOIN tag_rel AS tr ON (tr.item = i.id)
                LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON (t.id = tr.tag)
                $where
                GROUP BY i.id 
                HAVING (GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) LIKE '%$search%')
                ORDER by i.id DESC LIMIT 0, 10");
```

Now witht this query, I get all the Items that contain the "tag name" that the user $searches for.

But I also want to be able to search within the item's title.

I know I can't just add:

```
WHERE i.title LIKE '%$search%'
```

Because that won't allow the HAVING for the tags to work.

How can I get results for when $search is found in **either the Tag Group OR the Item Name**?

Any idea is much appreciated!

```
ie. scenario:
$search = 'jeans';

ITEM A)
GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) = 'trousers','long','jeans','skinny';
i.title = 'Skinny Trousers';

ITEM B)
GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) = 'trousers','long','skinny';
i.title = 'Skinny Jeans';
```

Comment: HAVING is very expensive, always use WHERE when possible, HAVING works post-execution (i.e. on the results) while WHERE is used before in order to achieve results. I suggest to have a WHERE, not HAVING, if you can explain better why you cannot use it. It would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're just trying to union 2 different set of results:

- The items containing matches in their title
- The items for which the tags contain matches

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, title FROM (
    SELECT id, title FROM items
    WHERE title LIKE '%$search%'
    UNION
    SELECT i.id, i.title FROM items i
    JOIN tag_rel tr ON tr.item = i.id
    JOIN tags t ON t.id = tr.tag
    WHERE t.name LIKE '%$search%'
) s
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your `group_concat()` method is needlessly expensive and prone to problems (if many names match).  An alternative is simpler:

```
HAVING max(t.name = $search) = 1;
```

If you want to match two different fields:

```
HAVING max(t.name = $search) = 1 or max(i.title = $search) = 1;
```

Given your data structure, the `max()` will only be processing one row, but that is ok.

Comment: I tried that with no results :(. I'm not sure what the Max = 1 is suppose to accomplish? Also I think the group_concat is necessary to get the list of tags, no?

Comment: The `= 1` is, strictly speaking, not necessary.  It is equivalent to saying that the condition is true for at least one row.  Your original query doesn't produce a list of tags, so I'm not sure what that part of your comment is referring to.